Angular does openapi-fetch library work together with tanstack library?
The openapi-fetch library does help to make HTTP GET fetches in a certain structure. The tanstack library on the other hand, helps to render components delayed, as far as I do understand.
Does it work and make sense to use them together? Or does one exclude the other?
Thanks!

Did you try it out? Are you experiencing any issues when using them combined? Please have a look at the [tour] and [ask]

I tried them both out individually. Is it not possible to ask other experienced developers if its generally possible? Already searched on google about it.

Questions on StackOverflow should focus on a specific problem related question, asking "Will this work" is not such a question. Why don't you try it out and if you have an actual issue, then please report back.
